# UNetBootin requiring a missing dwmapi.dll?

Tags: windows-xp, dll, unetbootin

I downloaded UNetbootin for Windows from [here](https://unetbootin.github.io/), and am trying to use it on a machine running Windows XP. I get the error:

> This application has failed to start because dwmapi.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix the problem.

Well, there was no installing: The download is an `.exe` file.

What's the problem and how can I fix it and get UNetbootin to run?

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out Windows XP is no longer supported with newer versions of UNetBootin, and that's why you get the error message.

The last version supporting XP was v681, which you can download from [here](https://github.com/unetbootin/unetbootin/releases/download/681/unetbootin-windows-681.exe).

[Relevant GitHub issue](https://github.com/unetbootin/unetbootin/issues/304).